# Accessing Items inside object

Tags: c#

I'm trying to access inside items that resulted from method invoke of .net reflection namespace. But I couldn't converted to any generic list type and array. There are my custom classes.

Here is my code;

```
foreach (Type t in theInterfaceInheritedClasses)
{                   
    object instance = a.CreateInstance(t.FullName);
    MethodInfo[] mi = t.GetMethods();
    object res;
    foreach (var method in mi)
    {
       if (method.GetParameters().Count() == 1)
       {
           if (method.Name != "Equals" && method.Name != "GetHashCode" && method.Name != "ToString")
           {
                res= method.Invoke(instance, new object[] {
                           wdoc
                     });
                IEnumerable resultItems = (res as IEnumerable);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

res has the items that I wanted to access. How can I do this?

Comment: Please clarify what "couldn't converted" means. Won't compile? Runtime exception? What? It's also going to be difficult to tell you *why* the return type of your method won't cast to IEnumerable if you don't tell us what that return type is supposed to be. Why do you think this should be IEnumerable to begin with?

Comment: First of all I would suggest that you use attributes to find the methods you are looking for. In your case you filter the methods by their name and parameter count. If sometime in the future a new method with 1 parameter will be added to let's say Object, your code would stop working.
You can achieve this by checking the CustomAttributes.
Second: What exactly is not working? Can you post the code of the methods you are invoking please?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the interface you're working against would be pretty relevant. And further, what are the concrete types you're creating? Remember that a concrete type *must* implement its interface, but it can of course have its own members as well.

Comment: Sorry, yes English is not my main language:) There is a custom type of mine for the items inside the object. When method was invoked, the method originally returns an array of my custom type.

When I debug, I can see the values.

Comment: There is not any exception. Return variable has value. But while res variable is converting, resultItems is null.

Comment: Again, *why* are you casting it to IEnumerable?

Comment: At first I tried it convert from a generic list. And I googled. There are some examples uses IEnumarable. Now it returns an array.

Comment: Infact, now the issue is to convert it from object to Array of my custom type.

Comment: If it make sense, method.Invoke invokes the method which is in another library.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I can solve the problem. I think this is a rule about OOP principals. Let me define my structure some:

I designed a windows app, can import DLL files that has methods to be invoked by my windows application. My app and the class libraries that will be imported, use the same POCO class. But at first these classes' namespaces were different. Then I recognized an error tells about type inconsistency. Then I made a new class library put them (my common classes) into this new class library.  And referenced this dll from all needed projects. Now I can convert the object to Array type.

Sorry If I confused you:)

Answer (score -2):

Exactly where do you want to access them? You seem to make the object "res" inside the foreach loop, so if you want to access it outside the foreach loop, you'll need to set it up similar to:

```
object res;
foreach(...)
{

}
```

If your question is why you can't get the values from res even though they should be there: You dump the data from the function in an object of type "object" (root type) and as such will only be able to access the methods from object. If you want to use the methods defined in your specific object, try converting the object to the proper type:

```
foreach(...)
{
   YourType res;
   ...
   res = (YourType)(method.Invoke(instance, new object[] { wdoc }));
}
```

Comment: The first part of your question is irrelevant and has nothing to do with the question. Why would he need to access `res` outside of his loop?

Comment: I am sorry for that, I got the vibe that Serhat wanted to do that from the sentence "I am trying to access inside items" (e.g. items in the loop from outside the loop). I assume English is not his first language, and it's not one of my main languages either, so there is always the chance of a simple misunderstanding.

Comment: Ah, understandable... I see your point, but I think his issue is that he can't access the items inside this object because of some issue casting it to an IEnumerable, not that he can't access his object outside the loop. You could very well be right, still waiting on details from OP to find out.

Comment: @tnw hence why I was so confused about being downvoted. Anyway, I guess waiting for more details from OP would be the best way to get this sorted.